# Hiding <th> in Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

Is it possible to hide the `<th>` element in the table? I know its possible on the `td's`. I've tried to hide `td's` if the value is null like the one's i've tried on my code below. Please see my code below. Thanks. Please see this link to edit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjkwzu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
<tr>
  <th>Date of Birth</th>
  <th>Nationality</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of bookingsForm.controls.profiles.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td *ngIf="row.value.date_of_birth !== null">{{row.value.date_of_birth}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="row.value.nationality !== null">{{row.value.nationality}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

In your component, compute a flag based on `bookingsForm.controls.profiles.controls`, like so:

```
public hideNationality:boolean = bookingsForm.controls.profiles.controls.every(x => x.value == null);
```

Then hook up this flag to your column with an `*ngIf`.

A more elegant way would be to build a `Map<string, boolean>` for every column and store a visibility flag in there. Then iterate over it via the `| keyvalue` pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, where do i put this public hideNationality:boolean = bookingsForm.controls.profiles.controls.every(x => x.value == null);? Thank you.

Comment: @GraySingh Your HTML template must be backed by an angular component, that's where you'd need to put it. (The component where `bookingsForm` comes from).
If you edit your question to include more source code I could give you a more in-depth answer.

The computation could also be written inline, but I wouldn't recommend doing that for various readability and performance reasons.

Comment: Hold on. Ill make a stackblitz

Comment: Here it is. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjkwzu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html. Thank you

Comment: I did, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-na1yy1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im sorry im using Angular 4.  And what i mean is the description i set it to null so <th> for description should be hidden. The entire column for description should be hidden

Comment: Sorry, had a bug there. Try refreshing it, it should work now.
If you edit one of the `descriptions` the column will show up.

Comment: Sorry i cannot compare the <th> since im writing it individually. Another scenario is when the <th> is different name than its corresponding <td>. So i cannot compare it.